# GraphX to create parent-child linkage in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, graph-theory, spark-graphx

I have the following table structure.

| group_id | id | parent_id | hierarchy_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 1 | 25 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 112 | 25 | 3 |
| 1 | 34 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 543 | 34 | 3 |
| 1 | 16 | 543 | 4 |
| 2 | 88 | NULL | 1 |
| 2 | 235 | 88 | 2 |
| 2 | 921 | 235 | 3 |
| 2 | 8 | 921 | 4 |

Eventually, I would like to get a structure which enables me to easily query the child_ids for a specific id I would analyze.

I don't have experience with graph libraries so I need a little guidance on what to look for.
I saw GraphX has plenty of algorithms. I've tried to check if there is one that I could use but I don't understand much of it.
As of now, I'm using dynamic loop which performs multiple joins depending on max hierarchy level.
However, graphs seem like something created for this purpose and they look more fancy.
Could someone more experienced give some advice?

Comment: Here are some two gists that I created. Unfortunately the questions to which these gists were answer have been deleted. 

https://gist.github.com/dineshdharme/c0125d6bcfc6099cc8bcb8f460e7a3a4

https://gist.github.com/dineshdharme/7c13dcde72e42fdd3ec47d1ad40f6177

Comment: @user238607 thanks for the reponse. However, I still struggle to use graphframe to get all subsidiary nodes for each node in my initial dataframe. Do you have any refrences?